# My Teacher just had a baby, how do I congratulate her

Tags: expressions, phrases, phrase-requests

My Japanese teacher just gave birth and our long-term sub is having us make cards to congratulate her, we need to write something in Japanese, and I want to write something different than what she supplied us with, to spice it up or whatever. What would be appropriate to say in my card?

Edit: I'm not exactly sure what I want to say, but the phrase the sub gave us was the same thing for the entire class:

> あかちゃん おめでとうございます

She said we could do something different, and I want it to be something that an actual Japanese student might say to their teacher had a baby to congratulate them. I'm only in Japanese 1, so I know hiragana and some words and phrases, but not nearly enough Japanese to write anything that would actually make sense in this context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll give a few simple common phrases...

> [赤]{あか}ちゃんのおたんじょう、おめでとうございます。
>
> かわいい or げんきな [赤]{あか}ちゃんのおたんじょう、おめでとうございます。
>
> ご[出産]{しゅっさん}、おめでとうございます。
>
> かわいい[女]{おんな}の[子]{こ}のおたんじょう、おめでとうございます。(← when the baby is a girl)
>
> げんきな[男]{おとこ}の[子]{こ}のおたんじょう、おめでとうございます。(← when the baby is a boy)

Maybe you could add at the top...

> 祝・ご出産

---

For those who want more formal phrases...

> ご出産、心よりお慶び申し上げます。
>
> 赤ちゃんの or お子様の ご誕生、心からお慶び申し上げます。
>
> 新しい家族のご誕生、心よりお祝い申し上げます。

etc...

Comment: Is there a particular reason you've spelt よろこび two different ways?

Comment: @AeonAkechi おお・・そうですね。。Either will be okay but お慶び申し上げます is more preferred.